# Knockout remap an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, underscore.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the following problem.

I get a complex object with json from a web service. I do:

```
 var myModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(costData);
 if (!modelBound) {
   ko.applyBindings(insuranceCost);
   modelBound = true;
 }
```

costData is an array of objects, so my model has an observableArray costs with this array.
In another ajax call I get some data to replace one of the objects on costData.
What I do is get costData from server and filter with underscrore and change the data:

```
var singleCostData = _.filter(myModel.costData(), function (item) {
  return item.PackageID() == costData.Costs[0].PackageID;
});
//singleCostData is the data that should be changed
ko.mapping.fromJS(costData.Costs[0], {}, singleCostData);
```

But my view doesn't change. Is there something wrong?

thanks

Comment: With respect to `ko.applyBindings(insuranceCost);`, are `insuranceCost` and `myModel` the same thing?  It looks like `insuranceCost` represents the ViewModel that you're using to set up a binding context.

Comment: `myModel.costData` is observable array, but you change the content of the array item. View would update only if items of the observable array would be observables. Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects